# generic method to print all elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, methods

I wanna a method that would loop any type array and print them, I have written the following:

```
public static <T> void printArray(T[] arr){
    for(T t: arr){
       System.out.print(t+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

but this one only works for class arrays, what if I have a `char[]` instead of a `Character[]`, or a `int[]` instead of an `Integer[]`, or is there a way to cast them before hand? Thanks

Comment: What about t.toString() instead of t+

Comment: Unfortunately array.toString() just calls Object.toString() and you get something like `[C@e6f8730` I suggested to the JDK 7 coin project lead he fix this but I didn't sell it to him. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey good suggestion. What was their argument against it? That everyone can make great use of that hash value?

Comment: They said you can use Arrays.toString/equals/hashCode to do what you want. I pointed out that Sun/Oracle supply 9 different helper classes for arrays including Array/Arrays/ArrayUtils in various packages and its a mess that someone new to Java shouldn't need to have to learn. (not to mention Apache commons and Guava) In fact you can hack/extend Object to fix toString() etc and the Idea/compilers accept it but its an ugly hack. So IMHO its not that big a change as you won't have to change the JVM or IDEs to make it work.

Comment: I heard Joshua Bloch looked at this, and I heard he felt  that to do it really properly was just too complicated.

Comment: by the way, generics is not needed in your code above: `public static void printArray(Object[] arr){ for(Object t: arr){ ...`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`java.util.Arrays.toString(array)` should do.

- [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) also have that - `ArrayUtils.toString(array)` (but prefer the JDK one)
- [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) allows for custom separator - `StringUtils.join(array, ',')`
- [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) also allows a separator, and has the option to skip null values: `Joiner.on(',').skipNulls().join(array)`

All of these return a `String`, which you can then `System.out.println(..)` or `logger.debug(..)`. Note that these will give you meaningful input if the elements of the array have implemented `toString()` in a meaningful way.

The last two options, alas, don't have support for primitive arrays, but are nice options to know.

Comment: Guava's Joiner only works for *object* arrays. For primitive arrays, you have the join() method in com.google.common.primitives (e.g. Chars.join() : http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html )

Comment: @eneveu that's in my last paragraph ;)

Comment: @Bozho: yes, but I also wanted to link to the join methods for primitive types, since this was what the questioner seemed to be after ;) It was not a critic, merely a suggestion to add this to your answer.

Comment: still, any particular call of `java.util.Arrays.toString()` does not work on "any type of array", as the OP wants. it can only work on Object[] or int[] or double[], etc. you will still need to separate out all the cases in order to work on any type of array

Comment: @newacct it works through overloading, yes. But if you have a primitive array, you know its type at compile time.

Comment: @Bozho: not necessarily. I could have an `Object` and it could be a primitive array or reference array

Comment: In commons-lang3 (and perhaps also in commons-lang), the ArrayUtils.toString() method has one striking advantage in some situations, as that it is capable of printing multi-dimensional arrays properly. The built-in version would just print the inner array's toString() values, not the actual contents.

Answer (score 2):

You cant write a generic definition for primitive arrays. Instead, you can use method overloading and write a method for each primitive array type like this,

```
public static void printArray(int[] arr)
public static void printArray(short[] arr)
public static void printArray(long[] arr)
public static void printArray(double[] arr)
public static void printArray(float[] arr)
public static void printArray(char[] arr)
public static void printArray(byte[] arr)
public static void printArray(boolean[] arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void printArray(Object arr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String arrayClassName=arr.getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (arrayClassName.equals("int[]"))
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString((int[]) arr));
        if (arrayClassName.equals("char[]"))
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString((char[]) arr));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass primitive arrays to the printArray() method

Comment: Thanks for answering, appreciate it.