# How to use Cookies to store a List of String Array in GWT?

Tags: gwt, cookies, gwtp

Based on the GWT ShowCase example (http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCookies) we can only store a Pair of String name - String value to Cookies.

What if we want to store a Triad such as (String ItemName, String ItemID, String CompanyID)? or even Foursome, FiveSome, SixSome.... of Info?

We can't set String Array for value in GWT Cookies

```
Cookies.setCookie(name, value, expires);
```

So How to use Gwt Cookies in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie is a key/value pair of strings, kinda like you'd do in a Java properties file. You can make some method that serializes/deserializes an array into a string and vice versa.

You can use the method described here to easily convert between Strings and arrays:
[string to string array conversion in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java)

And you can use `Arrays.toString(array);` to parse an array to a String. [Concatenating elements in an array to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957964/java-array-to-string)