# print TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>> in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to print the

`TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>> abbreviations` in Java

I tried:

```
if (abbreviations.size() > 0)
        abbreviations.forEach((x, y) -> {                     
            System.out.println(String.format("%-7s   : %-100s ", x, y)); 
        });
```

It printing like this:

```
US        : [ Unity Status,  Unresolved Sample]                                                                  
VC        : [ Value Color,  Value Contex,  Value Context,  Video Conference,  Visibility Created,  Visit Created,  Visits Completed]
```

But I like to print without square brackets.

```
US        : Unity Status,  Unresolved Sample                                                                  
VC        : Value Color,  Value Contex,  Value Context,  Video Conference,  Visibility Created,  Visit Created,  Visits Completed
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- Iterate over the `Set`, print each entry manually.

Comment: Vague duplicate of [Output ArrayList to String without \[,\] (brackets) appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774059/output-arraylist-to-string-without-brackets-appearing). But the good answer there using `String.join()` comes far down the list whereas here it’s the only answer so far.

Comment: Instead of `abbreviations.size() > 0`, you can write `! abbreviations.isEmpty()`, but this pre-test is entirely unnecessary. Further, `System.out.println(String.format("%-7s   : %-100s ", …))` is a verbose version of `System.out.printf("%-7s   : %-100s%n", …))`. Combining it with the accepted answer, your entire code should be `abbreviations.forEach((x, y) -> System.out.printf("%-7s   : %-100s%n", x, String.join(", ", y)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one of them is to use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) like this:

```
String.format("%-7s   : %-100s ", x, String.join(", ", y))
```