# Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 2

Tags: java, arrays, patternsyntaxexception

I'm trying to remove some words from the line. I don't want to prescribe them but replace them, because the words that I remove may increase. So I used an array. But when I try to do this, I get errors. I will be glad of any help.

```
 String[] a = new String[]{
                "\\bof \\b",
                "\\bor \\b "," \\bit \\b "," \\bto \\b "
        };
        String str = "asdasdas of or asdasd";
        str = str.replaceAll(
                Arrays.toString(a)
                , "");
```

Comment: It's always helpful if you show the desired result - so include what you want `str` to look like in your example.  I've included an answer which should help but if I misinterpreted your objective result then you'll have to "adjust".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer..

Problem #1: The `Arrays.toString(a)` returns a string which is bounded by `[]` so this is the result:

```
[\b of \b, \bor \b ,  \bit  \b , \bto \b ]
```

The brackets are special to regex to define the start-end of a character class definition.  `\b` in a character class definition does not mean "word boundary" but rather results in an "illegal escape sequence".

So first step is to remove the brackets from the regex string (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32774108/17856705)).

```
String regex = Arrays.toString(a).replace("[","").replace("]", "");
```

Problem #2: Your regex now looks like:

```
\b of \b, \bor \b ,  \bit  \b , \bto \b
```

This is not likely what you want - here's what I interpret what you want:

> Remove all occurrences of `of`  OR `or`  OR `it`  OR `to`  iff surrounded by word boundaries to include removing the trailing space.

(Note also the space after the expressions which should be removed.)

So assume we start with:

```
String[] a = new String[] { "\\bof \\b", "\\bor \\b", " \\bit  \\b", "\\bto \\b" };
```

So to implement the "OR" part you need:

```
\bof \b|\bor \b|\bit \b|\bto \b
```

And so the replace operation would look like:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\bof \\b|\\bor \\b|\\bit \\b|\\bto \\b","");
```

To continue using your array approach you could then use:

```
String regex = Arrays.toString(a).replace("[","").replace("]", "");
regex = regex.replaceAll(", +","|");
```

which yields the regex from your array (same as discussed before):

```
\bof \b|\bor \b|\bit  \b|\bto \b
```

And so

```
String str = "asdasdas of or asdasd";
str = str.replaceAll(regex,"");
```

yields:

```
asdasdas asdasd
```

I was a bit loose in the treatment of regex explanation so I would invite others to be more precise in their answers.

Good luck.