# Error while attempting to reverse the digits of an integer

Tags: java

I am trying to reverse the digits an `int` number, but the code provided below returns an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[null, null, null]"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at Solution.reverseInteger(Solution.java:21)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:30)
```

I know there should be an easier way to do this question, but I chose to do it in my ways. I have been Googling for quite a bit, but I cannot find any relevant solutions to fix my problem.
Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {

    /*
     * param number: A 3-digit number.
     * return: Reversed number.
     */

    public int reverseInteger(int number) {
        // write your code here
        if (number > 1000 || number < 100) {
            return -1;
        }
        String s = Integer.toString(number);
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        String[] b = new String[c.length];

        for (int i = s.length() - 1, j = 0; i <= 0; i--, j++) {
            b[j] = String.valueOf(c[i]);
        }
        String h = Arrays.toString(b);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(h);
        return y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution p = new Solution();
        int ff = p.reverseInteger(102);
        System.out.println(ff);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `for` loop.

```
for (int i = s.length()-1,j =0;i <=0; ...)
```

You set the value of `i` to

```
int i = s.length()-1;
```

but your for loop in only for `i <=0`, so it never gets entered into

and even when you do have `b` array, you can not just convert the reversed Array String to an `int` - add the below code and see.

```
    String h = Arrays.toString(b);
    System.out.println(h);
```

try iterating through the `b` string array instead

Answer (score 2):

You actually have two issues here.

1. Your condition in the `for` loop is incorrect. You start at `s.length()-1` and decrement `i`, but you are checking for `i <= 0` which initially is `false` which means your loop is never executed. The condition should be `i >= 0`.
2. When doing `int y = Integer.parseInt(h);` your `h` is actually the string representation of an array, i.e. `[2, 0, 1]` (after correcting the `for` loop). See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957964/concantenating-elements-in-an-array-to-a-string) for some more details.

I suggest getting rid of the `String[]` array and using a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead (trying to keep it close to your own idea). You can also get rid of some other parts in this case.

See my [updated version](http://ideone.com/l9ODmp):

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    /*
     * param number: A 3-digit number.
     * return: Reversed number.
     */
    public int reverseInteger(int number) {
        // write your code here
        if (number > 1000 || number <100){
            return -1;
        }
        String s = Integer.toString(number);
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(c.length);

        for (int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
            b.append(String.valueOf(c[i]));
        }

        int y = Integer.parseInt(b.toString());
        return y;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Solution p = new Solution();
        int ff= p.reverseInteger(102);
        System.out.println(ff); // 201
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really helpful.